# Function on Alter Database - Sent (Boolean) to Sent_At (Timestamp)

Tags: postgresql

I want to perform a function on a database column.

The function:
boolean -> timestamp | null

case true -> current_timestamp

case false -> null

I have a boolean field called sent and I want to change it to a timestamp

I would also like to change existing values in the database:

true should be given the current_timestamp, and false should be null

Comment: You can't change the existing boolean values to a timestamp. How exactly do you think that would work? What date and time would *True* represent? The only way to make the change is via `ALTER COLUMN`, and you can't possibly convert a boolean column to any sort of meaningful timestamp.

Comment: First, you're assuming I downvoted. Second, your question makes no sense. If you want a new column for a timestamp, add a new column. UPDATE it based on the value of the existing column however you'd like, and then drop the original column. You clearly cannot convert a boolean to a timestamp in an existing column.

Comment: @KenWhite You are literally the only person that viewed this except me. You're right that it's usually just better to create a new column then drop the old one, but I was hoping there'd be some kind of postgres shortcut for it.

Comment: Strange. I see 7 views, which clearly indicates that you're mistaken. Doesn't change anything, either. The solution is the same. Postgres doesn't have any magic solution that converts a boolean to a timestamp in-place.

Comment: postgres doesn't have something that lets you apply a function? like x -> func(x)? That's basically what I'm looking for, not some kind of magical function like you're stating. Obviously, you can't "convert a boolean to timestamp". I don't know why you're hung up on the boolean to timestamp part.

Comment: Not hung up - that's exactly what you asked. *I kinda messed up and made the column a boolean and now I want it to be a timestamp* is what you wrote. And no, Postgres does not have anything that performs magic to do the conversion.

Comment: @KenWhite It would be a good idea to check the documentation before you claim that something cannot be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would work as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE atable
   ALTER bool_col TYPE timestamp with time zone
   USING CASE WHEN bool_col THEN current_timestamp END;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5fc420962dbb1fa7e35a7b2f12c31988)